# Why is there no reduce in Guava library?

Tags: java, android, guava, reduce

I want to use functional programming in my Android app and as Java8 is not available I decided to use Guava Library. But apparently there is no REDUCE aggregate in Guava Library. If someone could explain why it is so, I would be curious to know, but what I need is a workaround.

How can I simulate the REDUCE/DROP functional programming features in Guava? For example how to calculate a sum or an average on a FluentInterface without coding myself from scratch (one of the main principle of Functional Programming, isn’t it?).

If you have done this with another library in Android, please let me know too.

Answer (score 9):

Guava doesn't support this, because the anonymous classes you'd need to build end up being significantly more verbose than a traditional imperative for loop.  Guava deliberately provides only a limited set of functional programming style features: see e.g. https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Caveats for details.

Let's imagine Guava did provide this.  It'd have to look something like

```
FluentIterable.from(integers).foldr(
  new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override Integer sum(Integer a, Integer b) {
      return a + b;
    }
  }, 0);
```

...versus...

```
int sum = 0;
for (int value : integers) {
   sum += value;
}
```

The second version requires significantly less boilerplate.  In the absence of lambdas in the language, it's just not worth it.

Comment: @u2gilles Additionally, there's no such thing as `BiFunction` in Guava - see [IdeaGraveyard](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#Functions/Predicates_for_n_>=_2_inputs) and [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=218).

Comment: Thanks Louis, for confirming and explaining that Guava intentionally has limited functional programming features. But I still think the REDUCE/COLLECT feature is a must in a functional library.
As far as your (or google’s) simplicity  reason is concerned, it’s a little bit trying to compare apples and oranges to my mind. There is a lot of hidden power in an underlying functional library which makes the comparison with your second example not really possible. Yes the second loop is simple but it is not "functional" as all.

Comment: Moreover, Verbosity is not such a big problem if the code is well indented.
 If I don’t find a simple workaround, I won’t use Guava in Android and I will try to find another functional programming library usable in Java6 Android. If you or anyone has suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Guava's perspective is that the goal isn't a functional style for its own sake: the goal is efficient, readable code.  Functional style is only useful insofar as it makes your code more readable, which it doesn't in this case.